# How to Iterate through an Array of Class Objects and use functions in JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, foreach

i want to iterate throug an Array of Objects and use a function from the Objects in the array. I'm coming from JAVA and there it's pretty normal to do that. For that reason i guess it works in JS as well but i'm not sure how.

My Code looks like this:

```
class Whateever {

constructor(ctx){
   this.ctx
   this.shotsFired = [];
}

onButtonPush(){
        let shot = new Shot(this.position.x, this.position.y);
        this.shotsFired.push(shot);
}

//called every frame
update(){
       for (let shot in this.shotsFired) {
                shot.update();  <-- I want to call this function
                shot.draw(this.ctx); <-- and that function
            }
}
```

--

```
class shoot{
    constructor(x,y){
       this.position = {
            x : x,
            y : y
        };
  }

update(){
// Do nothing 
}

draw(ctx){
// do nothing
}

}
```

But with this construct i get always the error message:

```
Whateever.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: shot.draw is not a function
    at Whateever.update (ship.js:40) 
    at gameLoop (index.js:23)
```

The shot.update() function works by itself.

I just want to know how to call object functions through an loop in an array?

This is an simplyfied snippit from a big class. If i would post the whole class it would be confusion. Question is absolute clear!

Array of Objects -> Iteration -> during Iteration call of functions from the Objects.

If u need an example i can post JAVA Code the make clear what i mean.

Comment: You need to make sure `onButtonPush` method is executed first. To populate the Array with `new Shot` instances

Comment: Your Shot class really has a function draw()? No matter what -  a working example of your code that clearly shows the problem would be more helpful.

Comment: Array has a `forEach` method to loop through it

Comment: Please add the shot class

Comment: @akinjide - If onButtonPush() wasn't called, shotsFired is just an empty array so it wouldn't ever try to call draw() or update() on an instance of Shot.

Comment: I guess the error message says it all, `shot.update` executes because it is a registered method and `shot.draw` doesn't because it is either not defined or not a registered method.

Comment: @RedDeadRabbit `If u need an example i can post JAVA Code ` No, we need to see your JavaScript definition for the Shot class. Looks like it's missing the draw function.

Comment: Just as stated earlier post `Shot` class too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to iterate through the array of something you can use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
let array = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}];

for (let item of array) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

So for your particular example, it would be:

```
update() {
  for (let shot of this.shotsFired) {
    shot.update();
    shot.draw(this.ctx);
  }
}
```

or even more simple:

```
update() {
  this.shotsFired.forEach(shot => {
    shot.update();
    shot.draw(this.ctx);
  });
}
```

Comment: @RedDeadRabbit `The Problem is not to go throug the array.` It kinda is though, because `for (a in b)` puts the *keys* in `a`, not the values. Use `of` instead, and it will work right away.

Comment: THANKS! What a big different between "in" and "of"

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
for (let shot in this.shotsFired) { 
   shot.update(); <-- I want to call this function 
   shot.draw(this.ctx); <-- and that function 
}
```

The for loop is actually iterating keys so you should do the following

```
for (let shot in this.shotsFired) { 
   this.shotsFired[shot].update(); <-- I want to call this function 
   this.shotsFired[shot].draw(this.ctx); <-- and that function 
}
```

However ultimately you should not iterate over arrays using this technique

Alternatively you can use many other iteration options available to you like forEach or for of